# OSX Mountain Lion server, PHP sqlite3.so "invalid library"

Tags: php, macos, sqlite, osx-lion

I'm trying to enable sqlite3 on a local server. I compiled sqlite3.so from PHP source (phpize etc.) and added "extension = sqlite3.so" in php.ini. When I type "php" in terminal, I get the following:

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'sqlite3.so' in Unknown on line 0

Can someone help me troubleshoot this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you use the right PHP version for source?

Comment: Besides, try [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/), it will make lots of things easier.

Comment: Have you looked at [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html)?

Comment: @Maxim Sqlite3 was already installed but I couldn't find the extension. I installed with homebrew again just in case, I'm not sure it installed any extensions anywhere. Also, yes, I compiled from the same php version sources that I compiled php from.

Comment: @TerryHarvey Hmm no I haven't seen it before. I'd prefer to solve this with the current setup, but if it isn't going anywhere I will look into MAMP, seems alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very simple, I just had to recompile PHP with a couple of extra flags that I had neglected during my first attempt. Those flags were "--with-sqlite", "--with-pdo-sqlite", "--with-pdo". I didn't even need to add or comment out anything in php.ini. Thanks everyone for your comments!